# FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN returns empty result when passed the string 'false'

Tags: php

Some code of mine has suddenly become 'broken' today and i'm trying to figure out what the problem is.

When I wrote the code, passing the string 'false' resulted in '0', however now it results in nothing, which causes an SQL error.

I'm running PHP 5.3.27.

My code:

```
$state = (bool) filter_var($_GET['state'], FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
```

Result of: process.php?state=true

```
$state = 1
```

Result of: process.php?state=false

```
$state =
```

Comment: Casting boolean false to string has produced an empty string since the dawn of PHP.

Comment: Can a mod please delete my question, for some reason I can't delete it myself. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are casting the result to `(bool)`, the variable `$state` is *guaranteed* to hold a boolean value `true` or `false`. When you `echo` a boolean value and thereby cast it to a string, `true` is output as `"1"` and `false` as `""` (an empty string). Your code can never have produced a "0" for a boolean `false`.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I use $state in a prepared statement for SQL, and  had forgotten to wrap it with apostrophes, which SQL wouldn't accept of course as I was passing nothing, not even an empty string.